# Comment dire « way » (comme « means », « method ») en français ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Comment dire « way » en français ? J'ai relevé ces deux mots en lisant des réponses sur ce site :

> façon
>   moyen

Sont-ils pleinement synonymes ? Qu'en est-il de ces autres mots :

> comment
>   genre
>   méthode
>   procédé

Puis-je utiliser le mot « chemin » ou « voie » dans ce but ?

---

J'ai mal formulé la question : je suis plus intéressé par le mot « way » seulement, j'ai utilisé la phrase « way of doing things » pour clarification et pour le distinguer de « way » comme « road » ou « path ».

Comment: **\*commentaires supprimés\*** Merci de n'utiliser les commentaires sous la question que pour demander des précisions, suggérer des améliorations, ou fournir des références utiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si l'on comprend *[way](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=method%20and%20means&source=english)* comme *méthode* et *moyen*, *façon* et *moyen* sont tout à fait corrects et ont le même sens dans ce cas, mais on ne les utilise pas de la même façon :

> Comment allez-vous résoudre ce problème ?

… laisse répondre sur la méthode, le moyen ou les deux.

> De quelle façon [ou *De quelle manière*, par quel *procédé*]  allez-vous résoudre ce problème ?

… interroge plutôt sur la méthode utilisée.

> Par quels moyens allez-vous résoudre ce problème ?

... interroge sur le moyen mais n'interdit pas de penser qu'une procédure (ou une façon) peut être entendue comme un outil pour résoudre le problème et donc un moyen.

*Genre* définira le moyen ou la méthode choisi.

Sur une autre thème :

> À ma connaissance il n'y a pas moyen de savoir si la phrase ...
>
> De quelle façon (manière) peut-on savoir si la phrase ...
>
> À ma connaissance je ne vois comment on peut savoir si la phrase ...
>
> Quels procédés utiliser pour savoir si la phrase ...

Answer (score 2):

Je traduirais « way of doing things » par « manière de faire » ou bien « façon de faire ».

Answer (score 0):

Parfois il est souhaitable de traduire *his way of doing things* par une expression telle que:

- [*sa marque de fabrique*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marque_de_fabrique)
- *sa signature*